# What is the maximum bandwidth of PCIe x1 3.0 riser to USB 3.0 and then to PCIe x16 3.0?

Tags: gpu, pci-express, usb-3

If I connect my gpu to a riser that uses USB 3.0 what is the maximum bandwidth availiable to my GPU? The PCIe x1 3.0 bandwidth or the USB 3.0 bandwidth and what would that be?

Comment: does it use a usb 3.0 cable or does it actually use usb ?

Comment: Please provide links to the products you intend to use. This all sounds mighty suspicious to me.

Comment: http://m.ebay.com/itm/6-PCS-USB-3-0-Pcie-PCI-E-Express-1x-To-16x-Extender-Riser-Card-Adapter-BTC-Cable-/182650884493?epid=924514723&hash=item2a86d7518d%3Ag%3AwfUAAOSwwzhZWghr&_trkparms=pageci%253A42a0e876-7b6e-11e7-b720-74dbd180588f%257Cparentrq%253Abcba584815d0aa18b3448529fff0583a%257Ciid%253A1 They all use USB 3.0 and the motherboard supports PCIE 3.0 and I suspect the risers themselves support PCIE 3.0. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: The max supported speed over usb 3 is 5000 megabits/second.  I think 3.1 doubled that.  However, due to protocol overhead you will get less. 625mb/s is the max, but 500-550 is probably realistic. PCIe 3.0 x1 is 925mb/s.

Answer (score 1):

PCIe x1 of course stays PCIe x1.

These risers do not use USB 3.0. They merely use USB 3.0 cables to transfer a single PCI Express differential pair (aka lane). This may or may not work. Because USB cables do not offer enough pins (9 out of 16 required), functionality of add-in cards in the riser slot might be severely impaired. SMBus and JTAG interfaces will be missing. Hot-plug will not work.

Because USB cables were not made for PCI Express signaling, the link may drop unexpectedly.